# Asynchronous access to resolved data in Angular2

Tags: asynchronous, angular, routes, resolver

I'm a little confused with `Resolver`s for `routes`. The problem that Resolvers solve for me is that an object is present in the component at rendering time. If I do it without Resolvers and start fetching objects in a component's constructor via Promise, accessing its nested properties in the template like

```
{{myObj.foo.bar}}
```

could lead to an error if the Promise does not resolve early enough, which is very likely when a http request needs to be done. However, the little info about receiving resolved objects from a Resolver tells me to do it like this in the component's constructor

```
this.route.data.subscribe(val => {...});
```

Isn't this the same sh*t as before? Ok, I admit, that the backend request has already finished, and I'll receive the subscription in no time. Nevertheless, I access the resolved data asynchronously again. There may be a very high chance that {{myObj.foo.bar}} is accessible at template rendering, but there is no **guarantee**, isn't it?

I don't know if I see that too critical. It's a gut feeling that using `canActivate` for the route and setting the resolved object to a Service that, in turn, can be accessed by any component synchronously comes closer to my intention, though.

Looking forward to clarifications

Comment: There's no guarantee when it will arrive, Just use safety checks `myObj?.foo.bar`, When the value finally gets there, it will rerender.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid. Using dozens of "?" operators in my template. Moreover, the ? operator means that an object is optional. However, on a profile page of a user his phone number may be optional, but the user object is NOT optional, it is mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole template or parts where you need to access `myObj` with `*ngIf`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myObj?.foo">
  {{myObj.foo.bar}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: That would solve the multiplicity of ?s (and would add an extra node in the HTML). Nevertheless I don't see the purpose of accessing data via a ``Subject``, that have already been fetched and are directly accessible. Probably I just am little too bullheaded, but "abusing" the guard pattern as a Resolver, that inject the data into a service makes more sense to me, at least in my particular use case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `<ng-container>` isn't added to the DOM (same as `<template>`). It's a helper element that allows to add structural directives using the same syntax as in other elements (in contrary to `<template>` that requires a different sytax). Resolver is fine as well of course. I prefer `*ngIf` because it's less code, but it also depends on the concrete use case. which fits better

Comment: Oh, another undocumented feature :). Thanks for bringing this up. I'm still not fully convinced, but this is definitely an option.

Comment: `<ng-container>` was added very recently.